# Magento 2 Categories not display

Tags: category-tree, magento2.1.5

Magento 2 Category tree not showing on admin's product edit page? How can I solved it?
[image]

Comment: Enable firebug and reload page then click on category tab and check JavaScript error and Ajax response.

Comment: Hi, @KumarM Thanks for reply, I have upload image of categories dropdown. Kindly check it. I am not talking about categories tab but I am talking about categories dropdown at product edit page

Comment: Have you checked any error coming in firebug console?

Comment: @KumarM, Yes I have checked in firebug console. But there is not any error.

Comment: @KumarM I had checked and found that product data was migrated from magento 1 to magento 2. So that's why it is not displaying. Have you a solution for it? Thanks

Answer (score -1):

Flush cache
Then hard reload.

I have the same issue seems to be a loading issue console is showing error on line 6 editor.js i did a hard reload and issue seems to be fixed just something not loading correctly.